# Javascript-Function displays a picture at particular months

Tags: javascript

Trying to code a javascript function of if statements that gets the month,then displays a picture corresponding with the number of the month.
   -(Ex.The first if statement gets the "springLogo.gif" if the month is ether
     "12" for Dec or "1" for Jan or "2" for Feb)
**The problem-an error shows that the "month" variable is never assigned? Dont know if this is the actual error or not.

===============================================================================

```
function displayBanner(currentDate) {
    var imgsource;
    var month;
    month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
    if ((month==12)|| (month==1) || (month==2)){
        imgsource ="winterLogo.gif";
    }
    if ((month==3) || (month=4) || (month=5)) {
        imgsource ="springLogo.gif";
    }

    if ((month==6) || (month=7) || (month=8)) {
        imgsource ="springLogo.gif";
    }
    if ((month==9) || (month=10) || (month=11)) {
        imgsource ="springLogo.gif";
     }
    if ((month==9) || (month=10) || (month=11)) {
        imgsource ="defaultLogo.gif";
    }

    alert(imgsource);

    return imgsource;
}
```

Comment: you sometimes use == and sometimes = when checking if month == something ... always use == to check for equality ... also, please show how you are calling this function

Comment: Attach code snippet please, then only we can debug your problem

Comment: are you missing  '}' in the last line of if  statement
if ((month==9) || (month=10) || (month=11)) {
        imgsource ="defaultLogo.gif";
}

Comment: Please tell us how you are calling this function, current implementation is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks! I should really get some sleep all of yall were right as I didnt have the additonal "=" in my if statements and was missing an "}" at the end of one.  Wow, pretty bad even if this is my first javascript program.

Comment: @Edward - have a look into the `switch` keyword. Much nicer than this cascade of `if`s.

Comment: @enhzflep - Thaks enhzflep, currently taking a class that hasn't got to the "switch" statements just yet. Though maybe ill get extra credit if I read ahead and show commitment. Thanks again..